# Add UINavigationBar programmatically to UITableViewController

Tags: ios, uitableview, uinavigationbar

I've been trying to add a `UINavigationBar` programmatically to my `UITableViewController` view. I know I can simply embed the `UITableViewController` to add a navigation bar, but I don't want to do that due to the way my app is setup.

I have tried the following:

```
    var navBar: UINavigationBar = UINavigationBar(frame: CGRectMake(0, 0, 320.0, 64.0))
    navBar.delegate = self
    self.view.addSubview(navBar)
    self.view.bringSubviewToFront(navBar)
```

However, the UINavigationBar just sits on the tableview (covering the first row) and scrolls with it.

The only way I have managed to make it stay (statically) at the top is to add it to `self.tableView.backgroundView`. Whilst this stays in position as the `tableView` scrolls, the `tableView` runs over the top of it, instead of underneath!

Can someone please shed some light on the view hierarchy here and tell me where I should be adding it?

Comment: I think navigation bar without a navigatonViewController is not a good idea . try to add a clear background UIView that is the same size with your tableview On top of your tableView  and then add your navigationBar on top of the clear view.

Comment: If you're creating the view with code you may want to look at assigning the nav bar to the UITableView's tableHeaderView if memory serves me this is static. But I believe it will be easier to set it up in storyboard.

Comment: I've been playing around with this the past few mins and I think it will just be best to embed in a nav controller and sort out my design to make it work! Thanks.